# merging two array with various object into one array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge the array which is having various object

```
array1
 $arr=array[{"zip": "560045", "count": 1}];

array2
 $arr1=array[{"city": "Bangalore", "count": 1}] 

array3
 $arr2=array[{"acount": 3, "answer": "fgdfgd", "question": "comment-about-me-"}]
```

Comment: $array = $arr + $arr1 + $arr1;

Comment: You can convert the objects to array and use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use php `array_merge`

```
array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3).
```

Try this code :-

```
<?php
$arr=array("zip"=> "560045", "count"=> 1);
$arr1=array("city"=> "Bangalore", "count"=> 1); 
$arr2=array("acount"=> 3, "answer"=> "fgdfgd", "question"=> "comment-about-me-");

print_r(array_merge($arr,$arr1,$arr2));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in PHP, you should use this way:

```
$arr = array("zip" => "560045", "count" => 1);

//array2
$arr1 = array("city" => "Bangalore", "count" => 1);

//array3
$arr2 = array("acount" => 3, "answer" => "fgdfgd", "question" => "comment-about-me-");
```

and then:

```
$final = array_merge($arr, $arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: If you need to convert Json format to array, use the json_decode function.